# Shall I put aws cloudfront in front of ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-elb

[image]
I've attached my architecture as shown as above. For HA, I've put ELB in front of my three API ECS instances. For security purpose (as geo restriction and so on), I want to add Cloudfront in front of ELB but I don't want caching that could be set TTL to 0. Please suggest me. Many thanks.

Comment: Can explain why are you planning to add CloudFront and how will it help. Also what kind of security features do you need ?

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande I want to restrict geo-location, custom header-type and so on.

Comment: cool. As suggested by Aniket then, you can use WAF and cloudfront.

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande WAF ***or*** cloudfront, right?

Comment: I think you can start with WAF and then if you run into any cases which cannot be solved using WAF, then add CloudFront.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add WAF or Cloudfront if ELB is internet-facing. Please refer to [DDoS whitepaper](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/DDoS_White_Paper.pdf) from AWS which lists best practices.

Cloudfront can be leveraged to protect against all known infrasture layer attacks.